# Flex Layout mixing rows and column

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]

I can make this layout using `float` easily. but having hard time to do with flex box.

css :

```
    .a {
      background: red;
      float: left;
      width: 30%;
      height: 100px;
    }

    .b,
    .c {
      background: green;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 45px;
    }

    .b {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .c {
      background: lightblue
    }
```

html:

```
    <div class="a">column</div>
    <div class="b">row1</div>
    <div class="c">row2</div>
```

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a front-end framework i.e. bootstrap / foundation?

Comment: No frameworks is being used

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [Flexbox codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJWdrK)

**How does it work?**

Wrap your columns in a common parent (e.g. a `main` element) with an height set. Then place your elements with `flex-direction: column` and create a space between `b` and `c` with `justify-content: space-between`.

The height of the column `a` is `100%` of the container so `b` and `c` can shift into a new column thanks to `flex-wrap: wrap`.

**CSS**

---

```
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
}



.a {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
}

.b, .c {
  background: green;
  height: 45px;
  width: 70%;
}

.c {
  background: lightblue
}
```

---

> [Grid Layout demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjepaR)

**How does it work?**

With `Grid Layout` you could achieve the same thing by creating a layout with `10` columns and `2` rows and a gap between `b` and `c` with `row-gap: 10px`. Then adjust all the various (`column|row`)-(`start|end`)

---

**CSS**

```
main {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
   row-gap: 10px;
   width: 100%;
}

.a {
    background: red;
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3;
}

.b,
.c {
  grid-column: 3 / 11;      
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 45px;
}

.b {
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.c {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using `grid` by wrapping `a,b,c` in a `grid-container`

```css
.grid-container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.a {
      background: red;
    /* width: 30%; */
    height: 100px;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    }

    .b,
    .c {
      background: green;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 45px;
    }

    .b {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .c {
      background: lightblue;
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="a">column</div>
  <div class="b">row1</div>
  <div class="c">row2</div>
</div>
```